# Shall retrieve value from a key in .reg file in Windows 7

Tags: windows, registry

the path in registry :
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Windows\MySoftware\Version1`
`Name: installpath`
`value: c:/Program files/MySoftware/`

How do I get the `installpath` value via .reg file syntax?

I have read MS document on .reg file, it can add/delete, but I don't find how to retrieve value. Any idea?

**update**
I am trying to use *.reg file to set registry.
Or whether .reg file can retrieve key's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no true way of actually retrieving the value of a registry key using a *.reg file. The .reg extension is not really a language but more like instructions given to registry editor to interpret and thus extremely limited.

The easiest way to grab values is by going to your reg editor, going to that path then in the file menu selecting export.

This will save that value as a .reg file.

To set a key use the following syntax

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Windows\MySoftware\Version1]
"installpath"="c:/Program files/MySoftware/"
```

Save that into file.reg and run it.

You can also use other utilities such as cmd and powershell if required to grab registry data.

Comment: If you are trying to get it in a specific way please provide more specifics, such as powershell, batch, etc.

Comment: pls see the update. I am using *.reg file to set registry.  title has already indicate the syntax is *.reg file

Comment: I edited my response in hopes that it is what you are looking for

Comment: thanks. the updated code is for setting the value. However I am looking for any way to retrieve the "installpath" value via .reg file. I just want to get "c:/Program files/MySoftware/" this string only.

Comment: I do not believe you can retrieve the value using a .reg file. You would have to use other means such as cmd or powershell if you aren't wanting to use the registry editor itself. I can help you using that if you require.

Comment: ok. finally I also think this is limitation of .reg file. would you pls edit your answer that there is no way to retrieve the key's value, and then I can mark your answer? thanks